# Get all lines from multiline textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have multiline textbox with HtmlExtender control from AjaxControlToolkit in my Web Forms application. And I have troubles with getting all of the text from textbox including linebreaks. I have this code:

```
Dim text As String = txtText.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>")
```

But I get only first line of text everytime. So I set a breakpoint and discovered that value (text) of textbox is always the first line.

[image]
[image]

What can I do with this, where is a problem? Is possible that there is any problem with ajax extender and textbox?

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I set `EnableSanitization="False"` and it works fine.

Code:

```
<asp:HtmlEditorExtender ID="HtmlEditorExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtText" EnableSanitization="False">
  <toolbar>
   ...
  </toolbar>
</asp:HtmlEditorExtender>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtText" runat="server" TextMode=MultiLine />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] allLines = txtText.Text.Split('\n');
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it does not help, because the value of textbox control is always the first line (look at the screenshots above).

Comment: I think problem is with your control, did you enable multiline property to be true?

Comment: Sure I did. I set TextMode="MultiLine".